# Hibernate validator not working properly on persist cascade

Tags: hibernate, validation, constraints, cascade

I've setup a ValidatorConstraint on a child class which works perfectly fine when I save the child class directly through JPA's save method. My custom validator is called & the validation passes for valid entities.

When I save the parent entity program the validator is called also but the weekPlan is always null - hence the validation will always fail.

I don't see what I'm doing wrong here? Is this a bug?

```
@Entity
@Getter
public class Program {

    ...

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "program",
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private final List<ProgramSetting> programSettings = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

```
@Entity
@ProgramSettingConstraint
@Getter
public class ProgramSetting {

    ...

    @Setter
    @Range(min = 1, max = 7)
    private int workoutDays;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Setter
    private Program program;

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "day_of_week")
    @MapKeyClass(DayOfWeek.class)
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "is_workout_day", nullable = false)
    @Setter
    private Map<DayOfWeek, @NotNull Boolean> weekPlan;

    ...
}
```

```
@Slf4j
public class ProgramSettingValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ProgramSettingConstraint, ProgramSetting> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(final ProgramSettingConstraint translation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final ProgramSetting programSetting,
                           final ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {

        val weekPlan = programSetting.getWeekPlan();

        if (null == weekPlan) {
            log.error("Week plan must not be null");
            return false;
        }

        val values = weekPlan.values();
        val workoutDays = values.stream()
                .filter(Boolean::booleanValue)
                .count();

        if (programSetting.getWorkoutDays() != workoutDays) {
            log.error("Week plan does not match workouts days of program setting");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you acquire an instance of `Program`? I bet somewhere in your code you call `Program p = new Program();` and then simply don't set the weekplan to any value. The default value for a field in Java is null, hence you see null if you don't initialize it. The usual pattern is to use this:

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name = "day_of_week")
@MapKeyClass(DayOfWeek.class)
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "is_workout_day", nullable = false)
@Setter
private Map<DayOfWeek, @NotNull Boolean> weekPlan = new HashMap<>();
```